# References missing within BibTex

Tags: bibtex, xetex, natbib

I am having trouble getting my references to show. Both my bib file and tex doc are in the same subdirectory. When I cite them, I only get questions marks and my references don't show at the end of the page. I am working in XeTeX if that makes any difference.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citet{asker:2010b} describes the setting:

\bibliographystyle{plainat}
\bibliography{bidrings}
\end{document}
```

My bib file looks like this:

```
@article{asker:2010b,
  title={bidding rings},
  author={Asker, John and others},
  journal={The New Palgrave Dictionary of Economics},
  volume={4},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Palgrave Macmillan}
}
```

Comment: For the person(s) who are thinking about closing this posting as a duplicate: It's *not* a duplicate of the earlier posting (about having to run BibTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs). Instead, the problem is caused by the presence of a **typo** in the argument of `\bibliographystyle`!

Comment: It looks like you've posted five queries to this site prior to this new posting and that you've received decent answers to all five queries. However, you've "accepted" an answer for only one of these five queries. On this site, the best way to express appreciation is to (a) **upvote** answers that you deem useful and (b) **accept** the answer you find most useful (by clicking on the checkmark symbol).

Comment: @Mico I didn't vote to close (in fact I voted Leave Open in the review). I'll delete the comment, but I'm not sure it'll help regarding the closing. If the OP confirms that you are correct, and the question is closed, we'll get it reopened.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number)

Comment: @MartinSchröder - This new query is *not* a duplicate of the posting you've adduced. The problem described here is caused by a typo in the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` instruction rather than by a failure to run BibTeX and LaTeX in the correct sequence. Please remove your comment and/or retract the "close" vote.

Answer (score 3):

There's a typo in the argument of `\bibliographystyle`: It should be `plainnat`, *not* `plainat`. If you inspect the `.blg` ("BibTeX log") file, you should find something like the following message:

```
I couldn't open style file plainat.bst
---line 2 of file x.aux
 : \bibstyle{plainat
 :                  }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file <\jobname>.aux
```

There's a second, separate issue you have to address: It's wrong to use the entry type `@article` for the entry at hand. You should be using `@inproceedings` instead -- and change the `journal` field name to `booktitle`. The *New Palgrave Dictionary of Economics* is a multi-volume book series, not a "journal" -- at least not in the usual, academic sense of the term "journal".

A full (working) MWE (run xelatex, bibtex, and xelatex twice more):

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bidrings.bib}
@inproceedings{asker:2010b,
  title={Bidding rings},
  author={Asker, John and others},
  booktitle={The New Palgrave Dictionary of Economics}, 
  volume={4},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Palgrave Macmillan}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % <-- not "plainat"

\begin{document}
\citet{asker:2010b} describes the setting:
\bibliography{bidrings}
\end{document}
```